# iOS - CGAffineTransformScale won't revert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgaffinetransformscale

Basically I want the button to be hidden initially, and when a some other button is clicked I want to change its transform to the origin, and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.btn.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.btn.transform, 0.01, 0.01);
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
       self.btn.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.btn.transform, 1, 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **CGAffineTransformScale**
>
> Returns an affine transformation matrix constructed by scaling an
>   existing affine transform.

So

```
self.btn.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.btn.transform, 1, 1);
```

will do nothing. You should change it to

```
self.btn.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: Don't think that's correct, setting to 100 will increase the size of the image by 100. Just tested it

Comment: @aryaxt just try it. 'CGAffineTransformScale(self.btn.transform, 1, 1)' does nothing. It takes already reduced 'self.btn.transform' and multiplied it by 1.

Comment: @aryaxt using 'self.btn.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;' could be a better way. I have updated the answer. Please check.